# Add or remove locked Unity launcher items from terminal?

Tags: command-line, unity, bash, launcher, icons

I've been building a very thorough script to handle the process of fresh-installing Ubuntu and setting it up just the way I like (as well as adapting it for use at where I work). It's a bash script I run right after install.

One of the last remaining things I haven't figured out how to do with something like gsettings is to control what icons get locked to the launcher. I would like to remove almost all the default icons and only lock icons of my choosing instead.

Any ideas?

Running 14.04.2, pure Ubuntu (not a variant).

Comment: Th link includes both an example script and the explanation on the gsettings key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key is `favorites` in `com.canonical.Unity.Launcher`:

```
$ gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites
['application://google-chrome.desktop', 'application://nautilus-home.desktop', 'unity://running-apps', 'application://evolution.desktop', 'unity://expo-icon', 'unity://devices']
```

You can set the values using `gsettings set`. For example:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites "['application://firefox.desktop', 'unity://running-apps', 'application://evolution.desktop', 'unity://devices']"
```

Examine the `.desktop` files in `/usr/share/applications` to determine the correct `.desktop` files for the applications you want to add.

Comment: Awesome! This is precisely what I was looking for. Thank you for providing such a quick and clear explanation!